# Sequence of patterns in R sequence and events issues

Tags: r, arules, traminer

I am trying to work with frequent sequences in R (SPADE).  I have the following data set:

```
d1 <- c(1:10)
d2 <- c("nut", "bolt", "screw")
data <- data.frame(expand.grid(d1,d2))
data$status <- sample(c("a","b","c"), size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
colnames(data) <- c("day", "widget", "status")

   day widget status
1    1    nut      c
2    2    nut      b
3    3    nut      b
4    4    nut      b
5    5    nut      a
6    6    nut      a
7    7    nut      b
8    8    nut      c
9    9    nut      c
10  10    nut      b
11   1   bolt      a
12   2   bolt      b
...
```

I have not been able to get the data into a format that seems to work with the various packages available.  I think the basic issue is that most packages would like to have sequences that are tied to an identity and an event.  In my case that doesn't exists.

I want to answer the question of:

If on any day the status of widget[bolt] is an "a" and widget[screw] is a "c" and on the next day widget[screw] is "b" then on the 3rd day widget[nut] is likely to be "a".

So there is no identity or transaction/event to use.  Am I over complicating this issue?  Or is there a package that is well suited for this.  So far I have tried arulesSequence and TraMineR.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do. If you would like to use `TraMineR`, here is how you could input your data assuming the widgets are your sequence ids:

```
library(TraMineR)

## Transforming into the STS form expected by seqdef()
sts.data <- seqformat(data, from="SPELL", to="STS", id="widget", 
                      begin="day", end="day", status="status",
                      limit=10)

## Setting position names and sequence names
names(sts.data) <- paste0("d",rep(1:10))
rownames(sts.data) <- d2
sts.data
#       d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 d10
# nut    b  a  b  b  b  a  c  a  a   a
# bolt   c  b  a  b  a  c  b  a  c   c
# screw  a  b  a  a  c  c  b  b  b   c

## Creating the state sequence object
sseq <- seqdef(sts.data)

## Potting the sequences
seqiplot(sseq, ytlab="id", ncol=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this type of question is most-easily addressed by reshaping your data from long to wide, and then implementing a logical test.  For example:

```
# reshape from long to wide
data2 <- reshape2::dcast(data, day ~ widget)

# get the next-rows's value for "nut"
data2$next_nut <- dplyr::lead(data2$nut)

# implement your test 
data2$bolt == "a" & data2$screw == "c" & data2$next_nut == "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to **reshape your dataset based on your objective**. You have to make sure each row has all the input information (your criteria/conditions) and the target variable (what you want to find out).

Based on the problem you described:

The **input info** is "widget[bolt] value at a given day, widget[screw] value at the same given day and on widget[screw] value the day after", so you need to make sure each row of your new dataset has this info.

The **target info** is "3rd day widget[nut] value".

```
# for reproducibility reasons
set.seed(16)  

# example dataset
d1 <- c(1:100)
d2 <- c("nut", "bolt", "screw")
data <- data.frame(expand.grid(d1,d2))
data$status <- sample(c("a","b","c"), size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
colnames(data) <- c("day", "widget", "status")

library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  spread(widget, status) %>%             # reshape data
  mutate(screw_next_1 = lead(screw),     # add screw next day
         nut_next_2 = lead(nut, 2)) %>%  # add nut 2 days after (target variable)
  filter(bolt == "a" & screw == "c" & screw_next_1 == "b") # get rows that satisfy your criteria

#   day nut bolt screw screw_next_1 nut_next_2
# 1   8   c    a     c            b          a
# 2  19   c    a     c            b          c
# 3  62   c    a     c            b          c
# 4  97   c    a     c            b          b
```

With a simple calculation you can say that based on the data you have the probability to have `nut = a` the 3rd day, given your criteria, is 1/4.

Comment: I see how that would work if I know the patterns I want in advance.  I wasn't very clear that I am in the discovery phase and I am looking for a solution to help me find the pattern.  The assumption is that the patterns can be of any length with many terms.